# How to check during delete Primary key using as Foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Student table, it very simple

```
s_id (pk)   s_name
1         Mr. x
2         Mr. y
```

s_id Using tables

1. Class

   ```
   c_id(pk), s_id(fk)  
   c1            1  
   c2            1
   ```
2. Library

   ```
   l_id(pk)     s_id(fk)  
   l1              2  
   l2              1
   ```

Now my problem is, when I will  delete Student s_id during this time I want to check this 1 (s_id) is being used as fk in Class, Library or many others tables

I want to check by passing table_name, key_name and key_value (ex. Student, s_id, 1)

query will return by checking all reference table simple true or false base on using this key.

Thanks

Comment: Using Cascade Delete can eliminate these type of queries.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query, apply the filters you need:

```
    select
        PKTABLE_NAME        = convert(sysname,o1.name),
        PKCOLUMN_NAME       = convert(sysname,c1.name),
        FKTABLE_NAME        = convert(sysname,o2.name),
        FKCOLUMN_NAME       = convert(sysname,c2.name),
        FK_NAME             = convert(sysname,object_name(f.object_id)),
        PK_NAME             = convert(sysname,i.name)
    from
        sys.objects o1,
        sys.objects o2,
        sys.columns c1,
        sys.columns c2,
        sys.foreign_keys f inner join
        sys.foreign_key_columns k on (k.constraint_object_id = f.object_id) inner join
        sys.indexes i on (f.referenced_object_id = i.object_id and f.key_index_id = i.index_id)
    where
        o1.object_id = f.referenced_object_id and
        o2.object_id = f.parent_object_id and
        c1.object_id = f.referenced_object_id and
        c2.object_id = f.parent_object_id and
        c1.column_id = k.referenced_column_id and
        c2.column_id = k.parent_column_id
    order by 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

You can take a look at `sp_fkeys` for further details